# Having Issues with Getting Pre-Loaded Case List to Load on CommCare Application

Tags: commcare

I created a CommCare application with the following surveys:

Household Survey
Child Nutrition
E. Coli Test Results
MUAC
Serology
Bacteriology

The case types for the aforementioned surveys are the following, respectively.

household
household_member
household
household_member
household_member
household_member

I created a pre-loaded case list by uploading an Excel spreadsheet through the Data tab on my application:

Data>View All> Edit Data>Import Cases from Excel>Choose File>Next Step. See the images below:

[image: Import Menu]

[image: Uploading Files]

My pre-loaded case list has the following case properties:

case_id (left blank), household_name (Household 1 - Household 10), gps (GPS coordinates in the format of latitude then longitude. See the image below:

[image: Excel]

I set the case type for the preloaded case list as household (see above for the case types of the surveys).

I was hoping that when I opened the CommCare app and selected the Household survey, the prepopulated case list with households 1-10 would appear, as well as the other listed case properties.

Is there a reason why my case list is not popping up? I should note that the Household survey is a registration form. I am not sure if that affects anything.

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason why my case list is not popping up? I should note that the Household survey is a registration form. I am not sure if that affects anything.

Since registration forms don't typically require a case the app will not display a case list. If you create a followup form then you should see the case list appearing.

One approach to showing a case list during a registration workflow is to use the [Registration from the Case List](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Minimize+Duplicates+Method+1%3A+Registration+From+the+Case+List) as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much @Simon!

Comment: Hi @Simon, many thanks for your help. Do you have any suggestions regarding how to connect GPS coordinates from a preloaded case list to a mapping application, such as Google Maps or OsmAnd? I added GPS coordinates in my preloaded case list, but they did not hyperlink. Here is a link to my inquiry: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/163960/in-need-of-help-on-how-to-link-gps-coordinates-on-a-pre-loaded-case-list-to-a-ma