# In Need of Help on How to Link GPS Coordinates on a Pre-Loaded Case List to a Map Application, such as OsmAnd or Google Maps, in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I uploaded a case list using the "Import Cases from Excel feature" referenced in the article here:

https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Creating+New+Cases+-+1.+Setup+Excel+File

On my Excel spreadsheet, I have the following case properties: case_id (left blank), household_name, gps (GPS coordinates), and owner_name for the mobile user. I am hoping to have my case list load such that clicking on the GPS coordinates would trigger the opening of a map application, either Google Maps or OsmAnd, though ideally both. See the image below for context:

[image: Excel Case List with GPA Coordinates]

However, when I access my Case List on the Commcare, the GPS coordinates do not seem to hyperlinked and cannot link to Google Maps or OsmAnd. Are they supposed to be formatted a certain way? See the image below for context:

[image: Case list has GPS coordinates, but the coordinates are not hyperlinked and do not connect to Google Maps or OsmAnd]

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do:

1. Make sure your GPS data is formatted correctly. In the screenshot above it looks like you have `{lat}{lon}` with no spaces between.
2. When you are configuring your case list you must select the "Address" format for the column with the GPS data.

Some more details on the help site:
https://confluence.dimagi.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=35651822#CommCareGeospatialFeaturesOverview(GPS,Maps,andDistances)-MapCaseList

Comment: Hi @Simon, many thanks for your help! It is indeed that I neglected to designate my GPS coordinates as an address. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JackJackAttack0214 Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Tl;Dr: Upvote helpful answers and accept if the one that offered the best solution. P.S. When there is only one good answer in most cases the it should be accepted but it's OK to not accept partial answers or leave the acceptation pending when there is a clarification request that was not yet adddressed.

Comment: Noted, many thanks for your help @Rubén!

Comment: @JackJackAttack0214 Just noticed that the link in my previous comment had a type. It's fixed now. P.S. Thanks for accepting and upovoting the answer.